# How to "set up as new" in Windows 8.1 installation?

Tags: windows, windows-8.1, windows-installation

I am re-installing windows 8.1 on my laptop. I had logged in using my Microsoft account in the previous installation. After re-installing the OS, while setting up the user, I logged in using the same Microsoft account and I selected option to set up as new. But it still used my previous settings in the new installation (wallpaper, windows explorer settings, taskbar position etc). How do I set it up as completely new? (none of the previous settings should be imported)

Comment: If you want to do that, then you can't use the same Microsoft Account, what is happening is your settings are being sync this is normal behavior.

Comment: Yes, I know that is default behaviour but in my case I specifically chose the option to set up the PC as new.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a 2-step process. First, turn off syncing (on all your devices if you have more than one using the same account):

1) Swipe in from the right edge of the screen, click *Settings* and then *Change PC settings*

2.a) Windows 8: Click *Sync your settings* and turn off *Sync settings on this PC*:

[image: 1]

2.b) Windows 8.1: Click *OneDrive*, then *Sync settings* and finally turn off *Sync your settings on this PC*:

[image: 2]

Finally go to [this page](https://onedrive.live.com/win8personalsettingsprivacy/) to delete your synced settings from the cloud. If you create a new user with that Microsoft Account now then it should start afresh and not import any previous settings.